# How do I increase the camera height in Command & Conquer: Generals?

Tags: command-and-conquer-zero-hour, command-and-conquer-generals

The camera height is way too low in *Command & Conquer: Generals* and *Zero Hour*. Is there any way to increase the height of the camera so I can see more on screen at one time?

Comment: For those wondering. The `Origin version` of the game does not allow for changing camera height. The accepted solution doesn't work. Would be pleased if someone found a way and added it as an answer.

Comment: @Valamas It works fine with Origin version, it's 2019 now, don't know if something changed but it works fine. Just edit the Gamedata.ini file.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is possible, the Gamedata.ini file has a setting called "maxcameraheight" which allows you to change the camera height. However this prevents you from playing with people (LAN or online) who haven't changed this value.

The Gamedata.ini file is located in installdirectory\EA Games\Command & Conquer Generals Zero Hour\Data\INI. If this file is not there you can download it and save it in this location. For example at: http://www.gamefront.com/files/10920361/CC_ZH_104_Gamedata_Widescreen_Update.

Editing the "Gamedata.ini" file can be done with a simple texteditor, set maxcameraheight to something below 1000, 600 or 700 is good usually.

Make also sure to set the resolution in this file to the resolution of your screen. Wide screen resolutions like 1600x900 or 1920x1080 are possible. If you haven't done this yet: set this resolution also in the "options.ini" file which is located at username\Documents\Command and Conquer Generals Zero Hour Data. Please make sure to do not change the options in-game because it will screw up this changes!

Comment: But how can I save it?
It's not possible to save after changing of MaxCameraHeight to '700'.
Or did I something wrong?

Comment: It might be set to read only, try using right-click and opening properties, then un-checking the "read-only" checkbox. If that doesn't work try opening the editor with admin privileges.

Comment: I know this is an older question, but hypothetically if you were to adjust this ini file, save it to your computer and give that same ini file to your buddy for lan gaming, would it still work?  or would you have to revert back to the original?

Comment: oh and awesome name kevin van der velden.  kevins are pretty awesome.

Comment: Copying it should probably work, assuming the resolutions are the same.

Comment: it was something i was always wondering about.  i had the same question about camera zoom when this game came out (oh many moons ago) and i never really did have an answer.  we played this game a ton in college and being the fact i was from the Red Alert original era, i really hated the new camera in Generals.  I'll have to give this a shot.  thanks bud!

Answer (score 1):

Easy fix

Set maxcameraheight = 600 in the file INI.BIG under Contents/GamaData/Generals Data

and INZH.BIG under Contents/GamaData/Zero Hour Data

In order to see the Content Directory, you must right click on the game under applications and select "Show Package contents"

You will need a hex editor to edit these files

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. I had to use correct case: MaxCameraHeight, but otherwise, spot on. Note - this is for OS X.

Answer (score 0):

OK so I just spent over a day researching on how to fix the resolution problem where you are too zoomed in because of mismatching of screen resolution to game resolution. You can potentially fix it with modifications such as Gamedata.ini, but that will restrict you from playing online due to the fact that it becomes a different version.

The only way to fix it legitimately is to download GenTool which gives more possibilities for adjustment of screen resolution in Options in the main menu of the game. The site of GenTool is not always working, so you can download it from <del>http://www.cncnz.com/downloads/track/file.php?id=420</del>. The only problem is that this won't work on the 17 years Ultimate edition pack. It will work on the First Decade pack and on the Generals (and Generals Zero Hour) game only.

Comment: Link provided is dead. [This appears to be the GenTool homepage, here](http://www.gentool.net/)